# cannot parse json Array start with [

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a json Array:

```
[{
"id": "xx",
"type": "xx",
"description": {
"type": "string",
"value": "xxx",
"metadata": {}
},
"imageurl": {
"type": "string",
"value": "xxx",
"metadata": {}
},
"location": {
"type": "string",
"value": "xxx",
"metadata": {}
}
}]
```

I want to parse it through Ajax with header request:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://192.168.xxx.xx", 
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType:"application/json",
                cache: true,
                headers: { "fiware-service": "smartcity" , "fiware-servicepath": "/"},
                error:function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                            alert("noooooo");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                         alert("yesssss");
    //for(var a=0;a<25;a++){


    //}

         }
   });
```

But I always get noooo, and didn't successfully get the json array, why? is there any problems with the dataType ? anybody can help?

thanks a lot

Comment: Try to change `dataType: "jsonp",` to `dataType: "json",` as jsonp is something else.

Comment: if I change it to json, I got  405 (Method Not Allowed)              XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://1xx.xxx.xxx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

Comment: You will need to update your post then with what you're trying to do, because ajax request are allowed only in the same origin eg. _example.com_ (simplifying) and if you perform ajax request to another domain you would need to allow for it. If you have full access to the resource you're requesting, you can adapt it so it wont return json but jsonp. Read about jsonp or about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, you can setup your server by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so it will allow for request from your domain.

Comment: But I can use postman to get json array from http:xxx/xxx a cloud VM .

Answer (score 0):

You can try `JSON.parse(input_data)`.

Ref: [jQuery loop over JSON string](https://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-loop-over-json-string-each-example/)